# Repl AIのユーザーIDをpythonを使って取得したい

Tags: python

**前提・実現したいこと**

Repl_AIをラズベリーパイで使えるよう、プログラムを組むこと

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

javaでプログラムを作った人がインターネットに公開していたので、pythonに直してラズベリーパイで使えるようにしようと試みたが、プログラミングの知識の不足のせいか、自分が作ったプログラムに問題があります

最後尾の行が赤く表示されてしまいます
（`return appUserId;`）の下

```
!/usr/bin/env python

 -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

REPLAI_API_URL  = "https://api.repl-ai.jp/v1/registration";
REPLAI_API_KEY = "xtPmepC69E5e7zw1ezSQX8WAFa421HcF3H0RR0E3";
REPLAI_API_BOTID = "raspberrypi";

def get(ReplAiUserId):

appUserId = '';
payload = {"botId": REPLAI_API_BOTID
};
headers = {"x-api-key": REPLAI_API_KEY,
"Content-Type": "application/json"
};
param = {"method": "POST",
"payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
"headers": headers,
"dataType": "json",
"contentType": "application/json"
};
try;
res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(REPLAI_API_URL + '/registration', param);}
appUserId = JSON.parse(res).appUserId;
return appUserId;
```

**試したこと**

可能な限り、javaからpythonに直してみた

**補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)**

参考にしたプログラムが公開してあるサイトです
https://qiita.com/sublimer/items/2c35d8068b7d2aaf9a5d

Comment: エラーメッセージが記載されていないように思います。質問は編集できますので、編集なさるのがよいと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。訂正しました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/108689